# Limiting decimal places

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, number-formatting, decimal

I have a basic question. I'm not really good at programming. I'm trying to display an answer to 2 decimal places in my answer field. I have my JTextFields and my JRadioBtn set. When the answer comes for for my area or perimeter, there are lots of decimal places. I just need it to round off the 2 decimal places. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class Triangle extends JFrame
{
private GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
private GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
JTextField firstNumberTxt, secondNumberTxt, thirdNumberTxt, answerTxt;
JRadioButton addBtn, subBtn, multBtn, divBtn;
JButton calculateBtn, exitBtn;

public ExamQuestion2()
{
    super( "A Simple Calculator Form." );
    firstNumberTxt = new JTextField( 5 );
    secondNumberTxt = new JTextField( 5 );
    answerTxt = new JTextField( 5 );
    addBtn = new JRadioButton( "area", true );
    subBtn = new JRadioButton( "perimeter", false );

    calculateBtn = new JButton( "cal" +
                "calculate" );
    exitBtn = new JButton( "exit" );

    JLabel firstNumberLbl = new JLabel( "Base: "),
            operationLbl = new JLabel( "Operation "),
            secondNumberLbl = new JLabel( "Height: "),
            answerLbl =new JLabel( "Answer: ");

    setLayout( layout );
    addComponent( firstNumberLbl, 0, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST );
    addComponent( firstNumberTxt, 0, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST );
    addComponent( operationLbl, 1, 0, 1, 4, GridBagConstraints.CENTER );
    addComponent( addBtn, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST );
    addComponent( subBtn, 2, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST );
    addComponent( secondNumberLbl, 5, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST );
    addComponent( secondNumberTxt, 5, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST );
    addComponent( answerLbl, 6, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST );
    addComponent( answerTxt, 6, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST );
    addComponent( calculateBtn, 7, 0, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.EAST );
    addComponent( exitBtn, 7, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.WEST );

    calculateBtn.addActionListener( new Calculator() );
    exitBtn.addActionListener( new Exiter() );
}

private void addComponent( Component component, int row, int column, int width, int height, int anch )
{
    constraints.gridx = column;
    constraints.gridy = row;
    constraints.gridwidth = width;
    constraints.gridheight = height;
    constraints.anchor = anch;
    constraints.weighty = 5;
    add( component );
    layout.setConstraints( component, constraints );
}

private class Calculator implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {
        String firstString, secondString;
        int choice;
        int firstNumber, secondNumber;

        firstString = firstNumberTxt.getText();
        secondString = secondNumberTxt.getText();
        if( firstString.length() < 1 || secondString.length() < 1)
        {
            answerTxt.setText( " INVALID" );
            return;
        }
        firstNumber = Integer.parseInt( firstString );
        secondNumber = Integer.parseInt( secondString );

        if( addBtn.isSelected() )
        {
            choice = 0;
            subBtn.setSelected( false );
        }
        if( addBtn.isSelected() ) choice = 0;
        else if( subBtn.isSelected() ) choice = 1;
        else if( multBtn.isSelected() ) choice = 2;
        else choice = 3;

        switch ( choice )
        {
        case 0: answerTxt.setText( ( (firstNumber * secondNumber) / 2 ) +     "" ); break;
        case 1: answerTxt.setText( ( firstNumber + secondNumber + sqrt(     (firstNumber * firstNumber) + 
                (secondNumber * secondNumber))) + "" ); break;
        default: if ( secondNumber != 0 )
                {
                    answerTxt.setText( ( firstNumber /     secondNumber ) + "" ); break;
                }
        else answerTxt.setText( " INVALID " ); break;

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Triangle MyCalculator= new Triangle();
    MyCalculator.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    MyCalculator.setSize( 300, 300 );
    MyCalculator.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    MyCalculator.setVisible( true );
}

private class Exiter implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

I have looked and tried a few things I have foind on the netbut cannot seem to get anything to work right. Anyone help?

Comment: Try `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`; there's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13903307/230513).

Comment: The example you gave me pretty much gave me my answer. Thanks for all your help. You're the best!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Try `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`; there's a related example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13903307/230513).

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
String.format("%.2f", numberToBeRounded);
```

For example, you can replace the line containing `case 0` with this:

```
case 0: answerTxt.setText( String.format("%.2f", (firstNumber * secondNumber) / 2 ) ); break;
```

The `%.2f` format specifier will display a floating point number rounded to two decimal places. See the [Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) documentation for more details about formatted strings.

Comment: I think conversions 'g' and 'G' use the precision as the _total_ number of digits in the resulting magnitude after rounding. You may want 'e', 'E', or 'f', for which the precision is the number of digits after the decimal separator.

Comment: Please say why this works. Your answer is in danger of deletion since it shows up as a low-quality post.

Comment: @deezy: You might expand your answer further by citing the `Formatter` syntax section on [*Precision*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `NumberFormat` for the display of your number, I would suggest you step back from the code and check out the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class for your numeric computing needs. You can set the scale `BigDecimal(BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale)` and effectively (read correctly) perform numeric calculations.